# Remove part of an item from the list

Tags: python-3.x, list, design-patterns

I have a list of data, I need to remove 2 characters after the dot

```
inp = ['AF,204,76.56781,N,106.20333,E,0.6,326.7,191122\n',
'BQ,204,24.2,23',
'AF,204,76.56786,N,106.20336,E,0.6,326.7,191122\n',
'17320953,\n',
'BQ,206,24.3,28,2893324',
'AF,204,76.56787,N,106.20339,E,0.6,326.7,191124\n',
'7,191124\n']
```

I need to get:

```
'AF,204,76.567,N,106.203,E,0.6,326.7,191122\n',
'BQ,204,24.2,23',
'AF,204,76.567,N,106.203,E,0.6,326.7,191122\n',
'17320953,\n',
'BQ,206,24.3,28,2893324',
'AF,204,76.567,N,106.203,E,0.6,326.7,191124\n',
'7,191124\n'
```

What I was trying to do:

```
check='A'
res = [idx for idx in inp if idx[0].lower() == check.lower()]
dotdel=[]
v=[]
for str in res:
    dotdel=re.sub(r'\b(\d+\.\d{3})\d+\b', r'\1',str)
    v.append(dotdel)
print(v)
```

the code removes the elements after the dot, but I do not know how to put the changed list data ('v') back into the 'inp' list.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you iterate over `inp` and check for your condition inside the loop?

```
check='A'
replace_pattern = re.compile(r'\b(\d+\.\d{3})\d+\b')
v=[]
for el in inp:
  if el[0].lower() == check.lower():
    el=re.sub(replace_pattern, r'\1', el)
  v.append(el)
print(v)
```

Note you can compile your regex pattern before the loop.

Output:

```
['AF,204,76.567,N,106.203,E,0.6,326.7,191122\n', 'BQ,204,24.2,23', 'AF,204,76.567,N,106.203,E,0.6,326.7,191122\n', '17320953,\n', 'BQ,206,24.3,28,2893324', 'AF,204,76.567,N,106.203,E,0.6,326.7,191124\n', '7,191124\n']
```